# How to alter all Request in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm receiving requests from new front end which encrypt all of the post parameters
the previous frontend didn't encrypt the post parameters
however the current backend also doesn't decrypt the post parameters received

how do i alter the whole request received so that i can put the decryption first when calling the

```
$request->get('param_name');
```

so that when the value of param_name gets into the variables to be used, it's already decrypted
because modifying the whole backend 1 by 1 is really inefficient

i've ever alter the trans() function, just go the file that handles it and alter it
but on request
what is the file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use middleware.

```php
php artisan make:middleware RequestInterceptorMiddleware
```

Then in the `handle` method you can interrogate the `request` and perform a `.merge()`

```
if($request->has('param_name')) {
    $request->merge(['param_name' => decrypt($request->get('param_name'))]);
}

return $next($request);
```

And then make sure to add that middleware to your `Kernel.php` in your corresponding route middleware declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You need create middleware for you action.

```
php artisan make:middleware RequestDecryptMiddleware
```

In Kernel.php add:

```
<?php

// Kernel.php

protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
'decrypt' => \App\Http\Middleware\RequestDecryptMiddleware::class,
...
];
```

After it you can overide params in middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if($request->has('encrypt_param')){
        $request->merge(['encrypt_param' => decrypt_function($request->get('encrypt_param'))]);
      }
      return $next($request);
    }
```

Then use it in you controller:

```
public function myAction(RequestDecryptMiddleware $request)...
```